Is there a way to turn off or not use auto battle?
So I like the idea of Pokemon following along outside their pokeball like in previous games, but I prefer to raise their experience manually myself. So my question is: is there a way to prevent Pokemon from auto battling and have them just follow along eg. a setting or held item?

That's essentially why it's called "auto-battle", its only purpose is to make the Pokemon battle with pretty much everything you encounter.
Not a real solution, there's a workaround: if your Pokemon's health is really low it won't engage an auto-battle (because it can't faint in that mode) and will always run back to you with a specific message:


By the way, if you press ZR the Pokemon will come out from its Pokeball and it shouldn't engage auto-battles, that's called Let's Go!. Conversely, pressing R will set auto-battle mode.

Oh so let's go and auto battle are 2 different things? The explanations I read made it sound like they were the same thing. So if I press only ZR and not R the pokemon will just follow along and not do any auto battles?

Yep, they are different modes, afaik. But you can always set the Pokemon to auto-battle by pressing R.
